# Undefined reference to 'event_base_del_virtual' when compiling libfluid sample controller

Tags: c++, openflow

I'm trying to use libfluid to code my own OpenFlow controller. But first I want to build the [sample controller](http://opennetworkingfoundation.github.io/libfluid/md_examples_controller_README.html) to understand how that works.
I got the following error when compiling the sample controller:(this is the error I got when I try `make msg_controller`)

```
c++ msg/MsgController.cc -lfluid_msg -lfluid_base -I. -O3 -std=c++0x -o msg_controller
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libfluid_base.so: undefined reference to `event_base_del_virtual'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libfluid_base.so: undefined reference to `event_base_add_virtual'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:10: recipe for target 'msg_controller' failed
make: *** [msg_controller] Error 1
```

Before building sample controller, I follow the [steps](http://opennetworkingfoundation.github.io/libfluid/md_doc_QuickStart.html) to build `libfluid_base` and `libfluid_msg`. When building these two library I got the following prompt which I think might be helpful to solve my problem

> If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
>   in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
>   specify the full pathname of the library, or use the '-LLIBDIR'
>   flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
>
> - add LIBDIR to the 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
>      during execution
> - add LIBDIR to the 'LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
>      during linking
> - use the '-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
> - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to '/etc/ld.so.conf'
>
> See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
>   more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.

Is the undefined reference error because the library not linking correctly?
Do I need to make some change to the c++ command?

I tried the command `grep -rn "event_base_del" /usr/lib` and also `grep -rn "event_base_add" /usr/lib`

The output for `event_base_del`  is below (the same for `event_base_add`)

```
Binary file /usr/lib/libfluid_base.a matches
Binary file /usr/lib/libfluid_base.so.0.0.0 matches
Binary file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevent.a matches
Binary file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevent-2.1.so.6.0.2 matches
Binary file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevent_core.a matches
Binary file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevent_core-2.1.so.6.0.2 matches
```

Is this means it is linking correctly? since `libfluid_base.so` is just a link to `libfluid_base.so.0.0.0`

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       22 Oct  8 09:36 libfluid_base.so -> libfluid_base.so.0.0.0
```

So how can I fix this?

After I tried using -levent_core or -levnet to have the example code link against libevent. The error continue exist, it's probably because the version of libevent I'm using right now is not compatible with the current version of libfluid.By the way I'm using Ubuntu18.04.

I will try build it on ubuntu16.04 with older version of libevent see if it works.

Comment: `grep -rn "event_base_del" YOUR_REPO` and see where this method is defined. Then verify if you link your code against the appropriate unit consisting of the symbol to that method.

Comment: I tried this command and I update my post. It seems like it linked to correctly library but still undefined reference?

Answer (score 0):

`event_base_del_virtual` comes from [libevent library](https://libevent.org/). Link it with `-levent_core`.